# Jenkins Integration with QTP in Virtual Machine

Tags: jenkins, automation, qtp, hp-quality-center

I'm trying to run a job from my Jenkins master to a Virtual Machine with a jenkins slave on it. 
What I want is to run tests that are on Quality Center in my Virtual Machine, but when I try to run the jenkins slave this error is happening.

[image]

Has anyone ever see it? Do you have any idea how to fix that? Does the master jenkins and the slave need to be in the same domain for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went back to the master jenkins and deleted my current node and created a new one. Them I downloaded the slave again and it worked!

If you're having this problem try this.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution.